# TableLayout layout_column causes error for API level < 24

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

The Application restarts before opening. I checked my java code and it's ok. and the application works in android higher than 7. This is a part of my UI **`XML`**:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_on"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="\u23FB"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorButtonOpEnabled"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="CE"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorButtonCEDisabled"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonTextDisabled"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_correct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="CORRECT"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorButtonOpDisabled"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonTextDisabled"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"/>
</TableRow>
```

When I remove this line or change it to 2 it works (I assigned 3 to create an empty space between button_clear and button_correct) :

```
android:layout_column="3"
```

and this is the screen-shot of the app:

[image: App Appearance]

Comment: Does it help if you add an actual empty View to the 3rd column instead of using `android:layout_column="3"` ?

Comment: yes, it gets alright. that was actually simple. thanks.

Comment: I posted it as an answer for you to mark as the solution ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an actual empty View to the 3rd column instead of using `android:layout_column="3"`